# Saving image to external storage not working in android

Tags: java, android, image, save, external

In my android app, I want to store an image to external storage. I have this code:

```
package async;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import http.Network;
import interfaces.ImageDownloader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Async_image_task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageDownloader callerContext;
    ImageView calledImageView;
    String link;

    public Async_image_task(ImageView calledImageView, String link) {
        this.callerContext = (ImageDownloader)calledImageView.getContext();
        this.calledImageView = calledImageView;
        this.link = link;
        execute(link);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Network.DownloadImage((Context) callerContext, params[0]);

        if (bitmap != null) {
            try {
                String[] segments = link.split("/");
                int len = segments.length;

                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                String imgpath = segments[len-6] + "/" + segments[len-2] + "/" + segments[len-1];

                File file = new File(path, imgpath);
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

                String abs = file.getAbsolutePath();

                OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);

                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();

                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(((Activity)callerContext).getContentResolver(),abs,file.getName(),file.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("IMAGE_ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        callerContext.ImageCallback(bitmap, calledImageView);
    }
}
```

And in the manifest I have this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But when it tries to execute `OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);`, it throws a filenot found exception....

**ERROR:**

```
06-18 17:48:35.573: D/IMAGE_ERROR(9316): /storage/sdcard0/arin/53/image.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Why is this happening, when I have the permission?

Does anyone know?

Thanks

**LOGCAT**

```
06-18 18:03:57.522: W/System.err(14213): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/arin/53/image.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at async.Async_image_task.saveImage(Async_image_task.java:64)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at async.Async_image_task.doInBackground(Async_image_task.java:37)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at async.Async_image_task.doInBackground(Async_image_task.java:1)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-18 18:03:57.532: W/System.err(14213):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-18 18:03:57.542: W/System.err(14213):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-18 18:03:57.542: W/System.err(14213):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 18:03:57.542: W/System.err(14213): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
06-18 18:03:57.542: W/System.err(14213):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
06-18 18:03:57.542: W/System.err(14213):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
06-18 18:03:57.542: W/System.err(14213):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
06-18 18:03:57.542: W/System.err(14213):    ... 13 more
```

Comment: What is the value of imgpath? And file.getAbsolutePath() ? Is this kitkat? Real device? Is the exception caused by the MediaStore call? Please remove to test. Add the logcat where you can see this.

Comment: imgpath:`arin/53/image.jpg`, absolutepath:`/storage/sdcard0/arin/53/image.jpg`. This is jellybean 4.1.2.

Comment: Is the file created? Did you add mkdirs() as Greg said?

Comment: When I check the phone in file explorer, it made a folder called "image.jpg"

Comment: I tried the mkdirs and the one with the parent like greg says below, both have same results. I updated the code above to be the current code I have in the app.

Comment: No that is not possible. Recheck.

Comment: Then try `File dir = new File(file.getParent()); dir.mkdirs();`

Comment: Actually when I check the error now, it says `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/arin/53/image.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`. And this is before your last comment.

Comment: I updated the manifest to have the read and write to external storage, but same results still.

Comment: You first have to solve the mkdirs() problem. image.jpg should not be a dir.

Comment: I think that problem was solved already when I used `file.getParentFile().mkdirs();`... It didnt make a folder called image.jpg.

Comment: ??? You said that that didn't work....

Comment: The folder didn't get created, but the problem is the file also didn't created and it still throws and filenotfoundexception.

Comment: Is the file created now? Please post more of your logcat because it tells which statement causes the file not found exception. Is that with saving or caused by the MediaStore call?

Comment: not related to the issue you're having, but something you should be aware of: this line `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);` is doing an I/O operation on the application MainThread. This WILL freeze/lock your application while it's executing. All this file operation you should be performing in the background thread (inside the `doInBackground` callback)

Comment: I can't seem to print the logcat, because the code requires it to be in a try catch. What else can I print in the log to be helpful?

Comment: I updated the code above to be the current code and the error message.

Comment: ??? try catch what does it matter? You can write `Log.d();` statements everywhere. But still you can post now already more of your logcat.  Try `new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());` Please comment the media store call.

Comment: PLEASE POST MORE LINES OF YOUR LOGCAT!!!! This will take ages if you don't.

Comment: I can't, the code requires the exception to be handled, so I have to put it in a try catch...

Comment: Complete nonsense i read here. What makes you think so? There are already more lines in your logcat. You only have to copy and paste them.

Comment: ok I found something, I posted above.

Comment: OK I fixed it, turns out it wont work when I have it connected to Samsung keys....

Comment: And why is the D/IMAGE_ERROR not included? Or did you comment the media store line? Post more please. The logcat mentions a function saveImage(). But we do not see it in your code.

Comment: What is Samsung keys?

Comment: http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP
its the software for the pc to manage things on the phone.

Comment: greenapps... some people ask for help but they just dont really want to listen or try... if someone doesnt know e.printStackTrace() well then what can you do for them really? nice try though, very persistent.

Answer (score 0):

The directory where you are trying to create the file may not exist. Try this line before you call `new FileOutputStream`:

```
file.mkdirs();
```

Comment: It didnt work, the error message was `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/arin/53/image.jpg: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`.

Comment: It should be file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); or something like that. Because now image.jpg becomes a dir too.

Answer (score 0):

Check for running sdk version is below lollipopOr smaller and than do this :

```
 File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            if (sdcard != null) {
                File mediaDir = new File(sdcard, "DCIM/Camera");
                if (!mediaDir.exists()) {
                    mediaDir.mkdirs();
                }
```